# Tomcat (with Liferay) not sending Connection keep alive header

Tags: tomcat, liferay

Liferay 6.2 ga3 on tomcat is not sending connection keep alive header in response

this is my portal-ext.properties file

```
theme.images.fast.load = true
theme.css.fast.load = true
layout.template.cache.enable = true
javascript.fast.load = true
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.cas.CASFilter=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmFilter=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.opensso.OpenSSOFilter=false
com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.validhtml.ValidHtmlFilter=false
session.tracker.memory.enabled=false
counter.increment=2000
portlet.css.enabled=false
javadoc.manager.enabled=false
direct.servlet.context.reload=false
blogs.pingback.enabled=false
blogs.trackback.enabled=false
blogs.ping.google.enabled=false
message.boards.pingback.enabled=false
permissions.inline.sql.check.enabled=false
look.and.feel.modifiable=false
layout.user.public.layouts.enabled=false
jdbc.default.jndi.name=jdbc/liferay
theme.shortcut.icon=favicon.ico
browser.cache.disabled=true
browser.cache.signed.in.disabled=true
layout.friendly.url.page.not.found=/errors/404.html
layout.parallel.render.enable=false
index.on.startup=false
last.modified.check=false
```

How to re-enable this header

Comment: Do you see the header when you don't have this configuration on? Reason for my question is that I'd rather expect tomcat to have a game in the keep-alive header, rather than Liferay.

Comment: its coming as connection close now,even without these header

Comment: I've updated the tags to include tomcat. This is not an application (Liferay) issue, but needs to be configured in your application server (tomcat). Liferay's configuration is irrelevant - please add your tomcat's configuration